# Grouping by query in solrj

Tags: solr, grouping, solrj

Enviornment- solr-8.9.0

```
curl -G http://localhost:8983/solr/testColl/select?indent=true --data-urlencode "q=*:*" --data-urlencode "group=true" --data-urlencode "group.query=UnivesityName:'University~' AND UnivesityName:'Toronto~' --data-urlencode "group.query=UnivesityName:'University~' AND UnivesityName:'british~' AND UnivesityName:'columbia~'" --data-urlencode "group.limit=30"
```

The following code is solrj implementation of the above curl query

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.Group;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.GroupCommand;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocument;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList;
import org.apache.solr.common.params.CommonParams;

    //Preparing the Solr query   
      SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();

      query.add(CommonParams.Q, "*:*");
      query.set("group", "true");
      query.set("group.limit", "30");
      
      query.set("group.query", "UnivesityName:'University~' AND UnivesityName:'Toronto~'");
```

How can I set multiple group.query (1."UnivesityName:'University~' AND UnivesityName:'Toronto~'" 2.UnivesityName:'University~' AND UnivesityName:'british~' AND UnivesityName:'columbia~'") in solrj API in order to create multiple groups, as described
in curl query?

Comment: did you tried by adding multiple lines of query.set() with different group.query value?

Comment: If you plan on having many of these `group.query`'s because of the `~` operator at the end, you might want to preprocess them into a single token instead and collapse by that field instead to avoid an ever growing number of queries.

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti... Thankx for reply!  i have tried multiple lines of query.set. with multiple values of 'group.query'...but last value is overwriting the previous values. and in output i am only getting only 1 group.

Comment: @MatsLindh...Thankx for reply!. Each token will be having 'AND' operator in a group.query....There will not be ever growing number of queries. It will be limited maximum to 5..... How can i pass multiple group.query value to solr-java api?

Comment: I'm not sure how to proceed. Any ideas?  Can you recommend a tutorial or link that covers this?

Comment: Did you try `query.set("group.query", query1, query2);` ? or `query.set("group.query", [query1, query2]);` ?

Comment: Are you sure 'UnivesityName:' should not be 'UniversityName:'  ?  (added 'r')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, `query.set` overrides the prior value. Try using `query.add` with the same arguments, ie

```java
query.add("group.query", "UnivesityName:'University~' AND UnivesityName:'Toronto~'");
query.add("group.query", "UnivesityName:'University~' AND UnivesityName:'british~' AND UnivesityName:'columbia~'");
```

The docs also say `set` takes an array, so you might be able to do this. This would be preferable, since it's a little less error prone since you can't forget that you added something.

```java
query.set("group.query", [
  "UnivesityName:'University~' AND UnivesityName:'Toronto~'",
  "UnivesityName:'University~' AND UnivesityName:'british~' AND UnivesityName:'columbia~'"
]);
```

Note I haven't tested these.

Docs: https://solr.apache.org/docs/8_11_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/common/params/ModifiableSolrParams.html (Note `SolrQuery` inherits from `ModifiableSolrParams`, which is what has the add/set methods)